# Cannot properly convert value from JSON dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I'm stuck on a weird problem.
I'm parsing a JSON response via Alamofire, and want to fetch a variable that just keeps throwing errors regardless whether I cast it to a String or Number, whilisting changing the error message every time I do :/
If I cast it to a String like this:

```
let kolicina = jsonCategory["kolicina"] as! String

if Int(kolicina) > 0 {
```

I get the error:

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10f051368) to 'NSString' (0x10e627b48)."

When I try to cast it to a NSNumber:

```
let kolicina = jsonCategory["kolicina"] as! NSNumber

if kolicina.integerValue > 0 {
```

I get:

> "Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10effcae8) to 'NSNumber' (0x10e5d32a0)."

This is what I get for that specific variable when I print the Dictionary:

```
 kolicina = 0;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: presumably this is in some kind of loop and the JSON contains a mix of numbers and strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a combination of strings and integers in there. I would recommend you to fix the JSON and keep the data either as a string or a number, not both.

If you want to parse such a format, you will have to try to parse it as a `NSNumber` or as a `NSString`, e.g.:

```
let kolicina = jsonCategory["kolicina"]

if let kolicinaString = kolicina as? String {
 ...
} else if let kolicinaInt = kolicina as? Int {
 ...
}
```

with the `> 0` checks you could do something like this:

```
if let kolicinaString = kolicina as? String,
       kolicinaInt = Int(kolicinaString) where kolicinaInt > 0 {

    print("String: \(kolicinaInt)")
} else if let kolicinaInt = kolicina as? Int where kolicinaInt > 0 {

    print("Int: \(kolicinaInt)")
}
```

or using a ternary operator:

```
let kolicinaInt = (kolicina is String) ? Int(kolicina as! String) : kolicina as? Int

if kolicinaInt > 0 {
    print("Kolicina: \(kolicinaInt)")
}
```

Comment: Indeed it was in a loop, but seems like Java just ignores this kind of stuff when calling their JSON methods, so the Android version never showed us how bad the API is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LeoStarić Java does not ignore that stuff but any Java `Object` can be converted to a `String` using `Object.toString`, including numbers. That means that if you ask for a `String`, the object gets converted to a `String` in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this .. don't make force unwrap

```
    if let kolicina = jsonCategory["kolicina"] as? Int{
        // Success: your kolicina is Int
        print(kolicina)
    }
    else{
       // Not an Int
    }
```